# Android App is slow

Tags: php, android, json, database, performance

I apologise for asking such a vague question, recently i have developed an app and given to one of my clients. the client integrated the features to the previous version and published the website. I have seen the user comments and some of them are complaining that the new design is slow.

What can be the reason for the application to be slow.
It basically pulls out data from the database and displays it into listview.
The database is accessed using HttpURLconnection and php and Json are used to retrieve the data.

I want to improve the app, but don't know how to start debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Move all your codes for Database operations to background thread.
Have a look at [Performance Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html).
Avoid memory leaks if any. Refer [Profiling with Traceview and dmtracedump](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)